# POST request is null at controller

Tags: javascript, c#

If i try to 'POST' my user it keeps arriving at the controller as null. I tried printing "data" in my chrome console and there i get the right values. I already tried everything I know ant this gives me the best result. But still i keeps arriving as null at my COntroller.

Below you can find my code snippets

my fetch:

```
let username = document.getElementById("username").value;
let url = "https://localhost:53342/gebruiker/Login"
var data = {
    username : username.value
}
fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    })
    .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            return response.json();
        }
        else {
        console.log("POST failed")}
    })
```

My controller:

```
public class GebruikerController : ApiController
{
    private readonly MockGebruikerRepository _gebruikerslijst;

    public GebruikerController(MockGebruikerRepository gebruikerslijst)
    {
        _gebruikerslijst = gebruikerslijst;
    }

    public Gebruiker Login(Gebruiker newGebruiker)
    {
        Gebruiker gebruiker = newGebruiker;
        bool alreadyexist = false;
        IEnumerable<Gebruiker> gebruikers = _gebruikerslijst.GetAllGebruikers();

        foreach (Gebruiker user in gebruikers)
        {
            if (user.Username == gebruiker.Username)
            {

                alreadyexist = true;
            }
        }

        if(alreadyexist == false)
        {
            gebruiker = _gebruikerslijst.Add(gebruiker);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("user already exist");
        }
        return gebruiker;
    }
}
```

My Model:

```
 public class GebruikerCreateModel
{
    [Required, MinLength(3)]
    public String Username { get; set; }
}
```

My repository:

```
public class MockGebruikesRepository : MockGebruikerRepository
{
    private readonly List<Gebruiker> _gebruikers;
    public MockGebruikesRepository()
    {
        _gebruikers = new List<Gebruiker>()
        {
            new Gebruiker("danny"),
            new Gebruiker("kind") 
        };

    }




    public Gebruiker Add(Gebruiker newGebruiker)
    {
        _gebruikers.Add(newGebruiker);
        return newGebruiker;
    }

    public ICollection<Gebruiker> GetAllGebruikers()
    {
        return _gebruikers;
    }
}
```

}

My Gebruiker class:

```
public class Gebruiker : IGebruiker
{
    public string Username { get ; set ; }

    public Gebruiker(String username)
    {
        this.Username = username;
    }

    public Gebruiker()
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: change username to Username

Comment: already tried that, it still is null when it arrives at the controller

Comment: you are trying to call Gebruiker constructor and initialize data?

Comment: I'm trying to Create a Gebruiker and add this one too a list<Gebruiker>, I also have a get function in my controller that returns the list and this one works fine. With this fetch i'm trying to make a new Gebruiker with the data from js.

Comment: [JsonConstructor]
public Gebruiker(String username)  // try this

Comment: still empty at the controller

Answer (score 0):

Just change below line of code:

var data = {
    username : username
}

you will get value in controller . you have already get value of html control in username. no need to use username.value in data section, this was leading to undefined value.

Comment: this still add's an Gebruiker with value null

Comment: I checked in below way and able to get value - 
  public ActionResult Login(Gebruiker newGebruiker){
   return View();
  } public class Gebruiker 
 {
  public string Username { get; set; }

  public Gebruiker(String username)
  {
   this.Username = username;
  }

  public Gebruiker()
  {

  }
 }

Comment: where should i put these code ? above in the Gebruiker class ?

Comment: I had just modified your code little bit for sake of simplicity ..you just need to change var data = {
    username : username
} in you script code. For sake of simplicity i had remove IGebruiker inheritace from Gebruiker class.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove .value from username.value because .value used to fetch data from html and you already have used .value while fetching data through DOM

```
var data = {
    username : username
}
```

Comment: Already tried this one, it still creates an empty Gebruiker in the controller

Comment: I exactly replicate your scenario and its working fine on my end

Comment: crazy , i'm already like 2 days busy figuring out this single problem. Is there maybe any option to upload ur scenario to GitHub and share the link ? would really appreciate that

Comment: I can upload my files on my drive and give you a link

Comment: Would really appreciate that

Comment: Try it out 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11oFquhE9vZm8t8R7HpFcxVWFdUq9uPLn

Comment: When i use that code he always pick the empty constructor, So my object stays empty.

Comment: Just simply use your ```GebruikerCreateModel``` model. It will automatically catch values

Comment: public void Login(GebruikerCreateModel gebruikerCreateModel)
        {
         
            Gebruiker newuser = new Gebruiker();
            newuser.Id = gebruikerCreateModel.Id;
            newuser.Username = gebruikerCreateModel.Username;                                          }                                                                                                                                                    I just tried it like this but it is stil empty when i use the CreateModel

Comment: Have you marked your method as POST method on ASP.net

Comment: I use [HttpPost] before it

Comment: https://github.com/JoranNuytsPXL/chat.git  I just added all the code to an open repos @ github.

Comment: Okay let me clone and run. Will get back to you